# Using JACOB SafeArray getDoubles() method

Tags: java, com, jacob

I'm trying to extract from an Excel Workbook a vector of double values.
Excel looks like does not return a unidimensional array, but a multidimensional one (number of dimensions is 2).

The data I have from Excel is in SafeArray format (I can have Variant too, but it's basically the same problem).

I'm looking for a fast way to extract the doubles array into a Java object, without needing to loop all the values in the SafeArray.

Looking at the methods in SafeArray there is this one:
getDoubles(int sa_idx, int nelems, double[] ja, int ja_start)

Obviously documentation is null, and I can't make up my mind of what this method does, since trying to use it gave me no results.

Thanks.

Comment: It gets part or all of a 1D SAFEARRAY into a Java array. Not useful in your case. You haveto loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here your data comes from a spreadsheet (Range object), not VBA code.

In that case, Excel will hand you a SafeArray of Variants (`Variant()` in VBA terminology), not a SafeArray of doubles (`Double()`), no matter what the contents of the cells happen to be. And you are correct that the array will always be two-dimensional (or it will return a single Variant if the range size is exactly 1x1).

I'm not familiar with JACOB, and yes, the documentation looks rather lacking. Could it be that `getDoubles()` only works when the SafeArray is a SafeArray of Doubles? Did you try to use `getVariants()`? If you get something back we'll know we're on the right track.

Keep in mind that performance-wise, you are stuck. somebody (you or the library) is going to have to write that loop. The Variants won't magically become doubles; someone will have to loop through the array, call Win32 `VariantChangeType()` or an equivalent method, extract the double field from the Variant (apparently in JACOB you call `changeType()` then `getDouble()`), and finally put the results in a Java double array. Whether JACOB will do this for you or you have to do it yourself, I have no idea.

Not being familiar with JACOB I'm not sure I I'm making sense, but I hope this helps. Good luck.

**[PS:]**
I feel I need to clarify that comment on calling `VariantChangeType()`. This is technically optional, but I find it generally healthy to explicitly convert variants to the data type I'm interested in via `VariantChangeType()` or an equivalent method. It's too easy for numbers to be stored as strings or something else, particularly when the source is something as free-form as Excel. This API call is exactly what VB/VBA calls when you use a function like `CDbl()`. Be aware that a bit of errant formatting is all it takes for you to be provided with a DATE instead of a Double.

If you are absolutely, positive beyond sure that all the cells will contain numbers (doubles) and Excel will never return to you anything else, then by all means call JACOB's `getDouble()` directly and skip the conversion step.

Comment: Hi,
yes, the data comes from a Range object, and from that I get the 2-dimensional SafeArray. And yes, it's made of Variants, but I know that I have doubles in that since we are dealing only with doubles. In JACOB SafeArray there is a method "toDoubleArray()" that does exactly that, converts to a double[], and it's native. That's what we wanted to use for the conversion, but we are stuck since we cannot directly (without a loop) extract the Variant in the 2-dimensional SafeArray that contains the values we need (the Variant can be converted easily to a SafeArray).

Comment: I tried also the getVariants(), but as with the getDoubles(), I'm not getting anything out of it. I must be missing something for sure here on how to use those methods. Thanks anyway for your input!

Comment: @Milo, sorry for not adding anything yet. I'm still scratching my head.

Comment: No worries... I'm still scratching my head too, but also have to take into account other work related issues. Since the procedure we have in place is working, we were only looking for an alternative, and hopefully faster, way. So, no rush at all! :-)

Comment: Can you post a (slimmed down) version of the code that does work? That might help me figure out how the single call version should look like.